# UISearchBar custom background issue

Tags: ios, ios9, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a problem with set custom background for UISearchBar. UISearchBar is added as header of UITableView. For set background I use next lines:

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "search_field"), forState: .Normal)
UISearchBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "search_bar_background"), forBarPosition: .Top, barMetrics: .Default)
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "search_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: .Search, state: .Normal)
```

As result I see that UISearchBar has background of UISegmentedControl
[image]

On other screens everything OK
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for that issue. The problem was that UISearchBar had 'Scope Titles'
[image]

I've removed these two titles and it started to work correctly 
[image]